# Show/hide visibility based on form values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hide, show

I want to hide/show a form div based on the selection I make. I already done this, but I need a different code because I have two forms in the same code and the scripts are in conflict.

Please see below the code that already works, but I need a second script which will not be in conflict with the one I already have.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#countries').on('change', function() {
        if( ['1'].indexOf( this.value ) > -1 ) {
            $('#state').prop('disabled', false).closest('div').show();
        } else {
            $('#state').val('').prop('disabled', true).closest('div').hide();
        }
    })
    .change();
</script>
```

```html
<div>
   <form>
   <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Job title<em>*</em></span>
                    <select name="dropdown">
                        <option>Select job description</option>
                        <option>Select job description</option>
                        <option>Select job description</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
   
   <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Country<em>*</em></span>
     <select name="country_list" id="countries">
          <option value="">Please select</option>
                         <option value="1" selected="">USA</option>
                         <option value="2">Russia</option>
                         <option value="3">Canada</option>
       <option value="4">Brazil</option>
       <option value="4">UK</option>
                    </select>
    </label>
   
   <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>State</span>
                    <select name="state_field" value="" id="state">   
                         <option value="1" selected="">Alabama</option>
                         <option value="2">Alaska</option>
                         <option value="3">Arizona</option>
       <option value="4">Arkansas</option>
       <option value="5">California</option>
        </select>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
   </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: I only see one form in you code. You could wrap the if statement inside `$('#countries').on('change', function() { ... });` and put it in a function where you pass the id of the form as a parameter. Use classes instead of ids for your select and assign the parameter to the prop() something like this `$( '#'+ formId + ' .state').prop('disabled',false).closest('div').show();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should not use the same id name on elements(divs, forms and selectors) for both forms.

Instead of, you may use class attribute to tailor your needs. Always refering jquery selector by parent form.

```js
 
        $(function () {
            $('.countries').on('change', function() {
                if($(this).val() == '1') {
                    $(this).parent().find('.states').prop('disabled', false).show();
                } else {
                    $(this).parent().find('.states').val('').prop('disabled', true).hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="form-1">
    <h3>Form 1</h3>
    <select name="country_list" id="countries-1" class="countries">
        <span>Country</span>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1" selected="">USA</option>
        <option value="2">Russia</option>
        <option value="3">Canada</option>
    </select>

    <select name="state_field" value="" id="state-1" class="states">
        <span>State</span>
        <option value="1" selected="">Alabama</option>
        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
        <option value="3">Arizona</option>
    </select>
</form>


<form id="form-2">
    <h3>Form 2</h3>

    <select name="country_list" id="countries-2" class="countries">
        <span>Country</span>
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1" selected="">USA</option>
        <option value="2">Russia</option>
        <option value="3">Canada</option>
    </select>


    <select name="state_field" value="" id="state-2" class="states">
        <span>State</span>
        <option value="1" selected="">Alabama</option>
        <option value="2">Alaska</option>
        <option value="3">Arizona</option>
    </select>
  
  
  
</form>
  
  
  
  
  
</body>
```